# How to solve 401 authorization error when trying to publish to GitHub packages from gradle

Tags: maven, github, gradle

This is my first attempt at publishing a package on GitHub.

I have set up [my project’s build.gradle](https://github.com/hansi-b/Moss/blob/master/build.gradle) according to [the instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-gradle-for-use-with-github-packages) - the relevant excerpt from the former being:

```
publishing {

    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'moss'
            from components.java
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = "https://maven.pkg.github.com/hansi_b/moss"
            credentials {
                username = project.hasProperty("GITHUB_ACTOR") ? GITHUB_ACTOR : ""
                password = project.hasProperty("GITHUB_REPO_PAT") ? GITHUB_REPO_PAT : ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using

1. my GitHub username as the `username` (in `GITHUB_ACTOR`) and
2. a PAT with the necessary scopes (AFAICS: **delete:packages, repo, write:packages**) as the `password`.

Both are set in my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`, and they look right when I do a `println` from the `publish` task. I have verified that with the right user name and PAT, I can clone a repo from the command line.

However, when I issue `gradle publish`, the result is:

```
Execution failed for task ':publishGprPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'GitHubPackages'
   > Could not PUT 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/hansi_b/moss/org/hansi_b/moss/0.2.0/moss-0.2.0.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

I get the same error if I mess up either the username or the password on purpose.  I have retried publishing with a different, private repository, and failed in the same manner.

Is there any way to get further information on what is going wrong? Is there some piece of configuration I am missing?

I’d be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was in your exactly situation and I resolved removing quotes in my properties file, like that:

```
//Before   
gpr.user="cappee"
gpr.key="key"

//After
gpr.user=cappee
gpr.key=key
```

I hope you can fix with this advice!

Comment: Indeed, after some attempts, it turns out this was definitely one of the problems :) - Thanks!

Comment: You said that was one of the problems. What were the others? I am also facing the same issue but doing this didnt fully fix it.
Thank you

Comment: Removing the quotes in my properties file resolved my 401 problem. Thanks @Cappe